# Terrain long distance object draw blue tint / fog Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, fog, unity3d-terrain

I have a basic 1000x1000 Terrain inside a very basic scene (almost empty) but the rendering for long distance is providing like a blue tint or like some fog :

[image]

The Terrain settings :

[image]

I tried increase all LODs or distances I found, even on the Camera object.

How can I get rid of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have [deferred fog](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Deferred-Fog.html) enabled in the Lighting settings, as it typically fades scenery far from the camera. There's also a setting for fog in [other settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-window.html#OtherSettings) which may be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks mate it was in lighting settings